# Anaconda virtual environment won't start?

Tags: python, anaconda, virtual, conda, virtual-environment

So I'm trying to create a virtual environment that runs python `3.5` with Anaconda. To do that, I created a virtual environment like so:

```
conda create --name pythonScrapy python=3.5
```

and then tried to run it by calling:

```
activate pythonScrapy
```

But when I then call `conda info --envs`, while the new environment shows up, the `*` signifying which environment is being used is stuck on the root one. What can be the reason that the comp is not switching my virual environments??

Comment: Which shell are you running it in?

Comment: @Amit just windows Powershell

Comment: Try running in `cmd` shell or the `anaconda` shell. It should work

Comment: @Amit It worked on the `cmd` thank you!! Why wouldn't this work on powershell?

Comment: Powershell doesn't support activate. You can try `call activate pythonScrapy`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Powershell doesn't support `activate`.  use `cmd` or `anaconda` shell.